# how to see method definition in chrome console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I accessed a website and opened console. 
On elements tab, I  found a button in HTML code that has `"onClick='request();"` code

I want to find the definition of `request()` in javascript.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just type `request` in console and press **ENTER**. it will return the function definition.

[image: As shown in this Image.]

This will only work If the `request` is defined in global Namespace....

Comment: where should I type 'request' in console??

Comment: In your console tab of the **developer options**.

Answer (score -1):

Inspect the element in Chrome Dev Tools (F12).
Select that element and choose "Event Listeners" tab. open "click" one and you will find that function.